# Active Objects: Cannot handle method. It is not a valid getter or setter and does not have an implementation supplied

Tags: jira-plugin, active-objects

I am getting the error:

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot handle method. It is not a valid getter or setter and does not have an implementation supplied. Signature: public abstract ...`

in a unit test run with ActiveObjectsJUnitRunner.
The project is an Atlassian Jira plugin with Active Objects.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that some my colleague wrote the getter as:

```
import net.java.ao.0neToMany;

@OneToMany
Collection<NdaProtectedItem> getNdaProtectedItems();
```

while it should have been:

```
@OneToMany
NdaProtectedItem[] getNdaProtectedItems();
```

The result must be a plain array, ActiveObjects do not support collection getters!